# Drapes crashed after adding too many wallpapers

Tags: 10.04, gnome, desktop-background

The wallpapers managing tool,Drapes, crashed after I add too many wallpapers.Drapes can't be started. I want to modify or clean the file recording the path of added wallpapers,but I can't find the configure file of drapes using `locate drapes`.

1. How to repair this problem.
2. How to uninstall it with deleting the configure file or environment of drapes.

Be thankful for any advice.

Comment: You should also file a bug report for this problem.

Comment: @João Pinto I will do that soon.thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file you are looking for is `~/.gnome2/drapes.xml`.
If you remove it and then start up Drapes again, Drapes will use the default configuration.

Comment: I delete many elements of **wallpapaer**.Drapes still cant't be started  with an interface.Using `ps` command,a process "drapes --tray" is running.